# How do you detect whether you have permission to query sys.dm_os_performance_counters?

Tags: permissions, azure-sql-database, azure

According to the [sys.dm_os_performance_counters documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-performance-counters-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permission):

> On SQL Server, requires `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission.
>
> On SQL Database Premium Tiers, requires the `VIEW DATABASE STATE` permission in the database. On SQL Database Standard and Basic Tiers, requires the **Server admin** or an **Azure Active Directory admin** account.

How can you check, from T-SQL, if you have these permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually we worked it out!

- If you're connected to SQL Azure Database, and the database tier is Premium, check for the `VIEW DATABASE STATE` permission
- If you're connected to SQL Azure Database, and the database tier is *not* Premium, check for `EXECUTE` permission on `sys.dm_os_performance_counters`
- Otherwise, check for the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission

The bit of this that isn't an obvious translation of the documentation is that "`EXECUTE` permission on `sys.dm_os_performance_counters`" is equivalent to "being a Server admin or an Azure Active Directory admin" in the case of non-Premium Azure SQL Database. This was just what we found by trial and error, and is not documented anywhere that I'm aware of.

```
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Result = ''

IF (SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') = 5)
    BEGIN
        IF (DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Edition') = 'Premium')
            BEGIN
                IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'DATABASE') WHERE permission_name = 'VIEW DATABASE STATE')
                    SET @Result = 'You do not have VIEW DATABASE STATE permissions for this database.'
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.fn_my_permissions('sys.dm_os_performance_counters', 'OBJECT') WHERE permission_name = 'EXECUTE')
                    SET @Result = 'You do not have server admin or Azure active directory admin permissions.'
            END
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') WHERE permission_name = 'VIEW SERVER STATE')
            SET @Result = 'You do not have VIEW SERVER STATE permissions within this instance.'
    END
RETURN @Result
```

Answer (score -1):

In the end - just build a query for said counters ... 
you should receive either results - or a matching error description if you lack the necessary rights/permissions.